# Sign up is just not working. how to go about fixing this?

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create user authentication with aws-cognito. The problem is console.log is not working and neither am I seeing users in the user pool in AWS. I am not getting any error messages but I am still unsure whether it a problem w/ my code or configuration w/ AWS.

I have looked through my code to see if there are any errors.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View,TouchableOpacity, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(config)




class SignupScreen extends Component {

    state = {
        username:'',
        email:'',
        password:'',
        confirmationCode:''

    }

    onChangeText(key, value) {
        this.setState({
           [key]: value
        })
    }

    signUp() {
        Auth.signUp({
            username: this.state.username,
            password:this.state.password,
            attribute: {
                email: this.state.email
            }
        })
        .then(() => console.log('successful sign up'))
        .catch(err => console.log('error signing up!:', err))
    }
    confirmSignUp() {
        Auth.confirmSignUp(this.state.username, this.state.confirmationCode)
        .then(() => console.log('successful confirm sign up'))
        .catch(err => console.log('error confirming signing up!:', err))
    }
    alert = (msg) => {
        console.log(msg)
    }
    render() {
            return(
           <View style={styles.container}>
           .................................
```

Users should be able to sign up w/ username, email, and password.

Answer (score 0):

**Amplify.configure**

> Somewhere in your app, preferably at the root level, configure Amplify
>   with your resources.

In your app’s entry point i.e. `App.js`, import and load the configuration file:

**App.js**

```js
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
```

**SignupScreen.js**

```js
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'; or import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.signUp({
            username: this.state.username,
            password:this.state.password,
            attribute: {
                email: this.state.email
            }
});

Auth.signIn(username, password)
  .then(success => console.log('successful sign in'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: In app.js, I already had                                                                                            import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './pages/AppNavigator'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './pages/aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(config);